# What are the differences among different versions of a movie?

Tags: film-industry, alternate-version

While going to download movies, I always feel at a loss when I see multiple versions of a single film are uploaded in a single website. I can see theatrical version, directors cut version and extended version of a single movie. So what are the basic differences among them? I searched Google, but it gave web result of different links describing difference among different versions regarding story a particular movie. So isn't there any general difference? If I am going to see the movie for the first time, which version should I download?